# Tikz beamer problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

It's the first time I use tikz with beamer and have no idea why doesn't work at all. The tikz code works perfectly if I compile with article as a document class. Can someone help me? I have the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}
    \usecolortheme{default}
    \usefonttheme{default}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \filldraw[fill=gray!40!white,draw=black] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
                \fill[black,rotate=45] (-0.125,-0.125) rectangle (0.125,0.125);
                \draw[-to, line width=1pt] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
                \draw[-to, line width=1pt] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
                \draw[line width=1.1pt] (-2,-0.1) -- (-2,0.1);
                \draw[line width=1.1pt] (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1);
                \draw[line width=1.1pt] (-0.1,-2) -- (0.1,-2);
                \draw[line width=1.1pt] (-0.1,2) -- (0.1,2);
                \node[black] at (0,2.7) {$y$};
                \node[black] at (2.7,0) {$x$};
                \node[black] at (-2.25,-0.2) {\small$-a$};
                \node[black] at (2.15,-0.2) {\small$a$};
                \node[black] at (-0.35,-2.25) {\small$-a$};
                \node[black] at (-0.2,2.25) {\small$a$};
                \node[black] at (1,1) {$V=0$};
                \node[black] at (-2.5,-2.5) {$V_0$};
                \node[black] at (-2.5,2.5) {$V_0$};
                \node[black] at (2.5,-2.5) {$V_0$};
                \node[black] at (2.5,2.5) {$V_0$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is de message I get:  

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Eduardo SuÃ¡rez\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-m
akemf.log
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Eduardo SuÃ¡rez\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Comment: Your code compiles fine and produces the tikz picture  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTfSP.jpg

Comment: Did you installed `beamer` using the miktex console?

Comment: No, but I've used beamer before with no problem.

Comment: I think the problem could be related with creation of some fonts to be used in different sizes in beamer.

Comment: Off-topic: each package and library load onlyonce. Also consider, that `beamer` load some packages as `amsmath` etc. Also `beamer` has own `multicol` environment, better is to use it than load new package. Why you use `utf8x`, `utf8` should be sufficient.